# How to match an empty dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.10, structural-pattern-matching

Python supports [Structural Pattern Matching](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/) since version `3.10`.
I came to notice that matching an empty `dict` doesn't work by simply matching `{}` as it does for `list`s.
According to my naive approach, non-empty `dict`s are also matched (Python 3.10.4):

```py
def match_empty(m):
    match m:
        case []:
            print("empty list")
        case {}:
            print("empty dict")
        case _:
            print("not empty")
```

```py
match_empty([])           # empty list
match_empty([1, 2])       # not empty
match_empty({})           # empty dict
match_empty({'a': 1})     # empty dict
```

Matching the constructors even breaks the empty list matching:

```py
def match_empty(m):
    match m:
        case list():
            print("empty list")
        case dict():
            print("empty dict")
        case _:
            print("not empty")
```

```py
match_empty([])           # empty list
match_empty([1, 2])       # empty list
match_empty({})           # empty dict
match_empty({'a': 1})     # empty dict
```

Here is a solution, that works as I expect:

```py
def match_empty(m):
    match m:
        case []:
            print("empty list")
        case d:
            if isinstance(d, dict) and len(d) == 0:
                print("empty dict")
                return
            print("not empty")
```

```py
match_empty([])           # empty list
match_empty([1, 2])       # not empty
match_empty({})           # empty dict
match_empty({'a': 1})     # not empty
```

Now my questions are:

- Why do my first 2 approaches not work (as expected)?
- Is there a way to use structural pattern matching to match only an empty `dict` (without checking the `dict` length explicitly)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a *mapping* (dict) as the match pattern works a bit differently than using a sequence (list). You can match the dict's structure by key-value pairs where the key is a literal and the value can be a capture pattern so it is used in the `case`.

You can use `**rest` within a mapping pattern to capture additional keys in the subject. The main difference with lists is - [***"extra keys in the subject will be ignored while matching"***](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/#going-to-the-cloud-mappings).

So when you use `{}` as a case, what you're really telling Python is *"match a dict, no constraints whatsoever*", and not *"match an empty dict"*. So one way that might be slightly more elegant than your last attempt is:

```py
def match_empty(m):
    match m:
        case []:
            print("empty list")
        case {**keys}:
            if keys:
                print("non-empty dict")
            else:
                print("empty dict")
        case _:
            print("not empty")
```

---

I think the main reason this feels awkward and doesn't work good is because the feature wasn't intended to work with mixed types like this. i.e. you're using the feature as a type-checker first and then as pattern matching. If you ***knew*** that `m` is a dict (and wanted to match its *"insides"*), this would work much nicer.

Answer (score 4):

[As specified](https://peps.python.org/pep-0634/#mapping-patterns), mapping captures are used to match on some substructure of keys/values. An empty dict is a "subdict" of any non-empty dict, so the pattern `{}` may capture any non-empty dict.

You can add a [guard](https://peps.python.org/pep-0634/#guards) to specify that there are no "extra" items present:

```
>>> def match_empty(m):
...     match m:
...         case []:
...             print("empty list")
...         case {**extra} if not extra:
...             print("empty dict")
...         case _:
...             print("not empty")
... 
>>> match_empty({})
empty dict
>>> match_empty({1:1})
not empty
```

For some justification of why mapping patterns allow extra items by default, refer to [*PEP 635 – Structural Pattern Matching: Motivation and Rationale*](https://peps.python.org/pep-0635/#mapping-patterns):

> The mapping pattern reflects the common usage of dictionary lookup: it allows the user to extract some values from a mapping by means of constant/known keys and have the values match given subpatterns. Extra keys in the subject are ignored even if `**rest` is not present. This is different from sequence patterns, where extra items will cause a match to fail. But mappings are actually different from sequences: they have natural structural sub-typing behavior, i.e., passing a dictionary with extra keys somewhere will likely just work.

Finally, there was a slight misconception in the question that may be worth pointing out here:

> Matching the constructors even breaks the empty list matching

This is not "matching the constructors". No actual list or dict instance will be created by the `list()` or `dict()` written there. It's just the [normal way to match on types](https://peps.python.org/pep-0635/#class-patterns). It can't be just `list` or `dict` because that would be a name binding.